# Formatting Number in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating an app with Phonegap and JQuery Mobile and have a particular scenario where I need to format a particular counter.

Basically the counter starts from 1 and keeps increasing showing the distance travelled. However, in order to display it I need to display them as 0001 then once an event is triggered it goes to 0002 .... 0099... 0999... 9999 (max).

The issue is that when the distance travelled is less than 1KM, I need to show the decimal point.  Therefore since I am limited to show the 4 digits, I need to show the distance as:
0.250KM (which would be equivalent to 250m).

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this so that once the number is less than 1, it shows up as for example 0.005 then 0.025, then 0.250, until it hits 0.999 which then it would round to 0001.

At the moment I had this setup:

```
var newDist = Math.round((geoLocationHandler.distance/1000)); // shows distance in KM
var distance = parseInt($('.distanceTravelled').text(), 10);
$('.distanceTravelled').text(("000"+ (distance+newDist)).slice(-4));
```

And HTML

```
<span class="distanceTravelled">0000</span>km
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function padNumber(number, padding, length) {
    var string = (Math.round( number * 1000 ) / 1000)+ '';
    if(number < 1 && number != 0){
        while (string.length <= length){
            string += padding;
        }
    } else {
        while (string.length < length){
            string = padding + string;
        }
    }
    return string;
}

padNumber(0.23, 0, 4);
//"0.230";
padNumber(23, 0, 4);
//"0023";
padNumber(23.5, 0, 4)
//"0024"
padNumber(0.95512154, 0, 4)
//"0.950"
```

Keep in mind that this doesn't add the `'KM'` suffix, yet. You could do that with:

```
return string + 'KM';
```

Comment: Would the person that downvoted me please explain why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Comment: @AspiringAqib: That'd be nice, yes.

Comment: well, what? watch this! http://jsfiddle.net/3gmYp/3/ oh man still editing needed! the examples you gave me in my answer does not works in your own!

Comment: @Cerbrus the KM suffix can be added in the HTML so it is not a problem.  The problem is when the distance number is long as in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/3gmYp/4/

Comment: @AspiringAqib: what's exactly the issue, there? user1809790: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Change the second line to `var string = Math.round( number * 1000 ) / 1000 + '';` (http://jsfiddle.net/3gmYp/5/)

Comment: @Juhana you had to post it as a answer buddy! why you gave it to him?

Comment: I'm not going to steal another dude's answer with just one minor change.

Comment: @Juhana it was not a minor change though!

Comment: @Juhana: Thanks, I added your rounding instead of my `.substring(0, length)` idea I just had ^_^
@AspiringAqib: What's your problem, dude?

Comment: In this case, what is going wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/6YpAG/5/

The distance will be outputted from the geolocation handler.  I am first showing the value in meters in an alert and the value in KM on the side.  The answer seems to be wrong though

Comment: @user1809790: In that case, it seems you're entering the distance in meters, in the function. The function expects KM (So, divide by `1000`)

Answer (score 0):

It's crazy but works:

```
var a = .999;

function padder(a) {
    var hasDecimal = $.inArray('.', a.toString().split('')) !== -1,
        b = (hasDecimal ? a.toFixed(3): a.toString()).split(''),
        zeros = hasDecimal ? '00000' : '0000';

    return $.map(zeros.split(''), function (i) {
       return b.pop() || i;
    }).reverse().join('');
}
```

the `reverse()` is used to fix the `pop()` action. I use pop to guarantee I'm the rightmost digits at the beginning of the array. So, ".250" would go `-> 0, 5, 2, ., 0`. I need to reverse that and join the array back into a string.

Comment: What's a `reverse()` doing in there? I'm looking at the code, and having a bit of a meltdown trying to figure out what the second half does. Could you try to explain it a bit, please?

Comment: @Joe sorry but I consider myself a N00B when it comes to such complex stuff.  So I presume var 'a' would be equivalent to my 'newDist' but then how can I output the value to $('.distanceTravelled')?

Comment: It's the same as my function: `$('.distanceTravelled').text(padder(newDist) + 'KM');` (Except in my case the function is called `padNumber`)

Comment: @Joe when you have a long distance it seems that it doesnt work properly http://jsfiddle.net/6YpAG/6/ (unless I did something wrong)

Comment: I didn't know large numbers were included in your set; so this wouldn't work with those.